# How do I tell conan2 where to install things?

Tags: installation, conan-2

With conan 1.x, we installed using

```
conan install -if="/path/to/installation/target" /path/to/dir/with/conanfile.py
```

but now, with Conan 2.0.16, `conan install` doesn't seem to have an `-if` or similar argument, and I don't know where it installs by default, either. How do I choose the install folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [Conan 2 migration guide](https://docs.conan.io/1/migrating_to_2.0/commands.html#conan-install) has the info you're looking for:

> In addition the --install-folder has been replaced with --output-folder. You might need to provide both arguments in Conan 1.X as some legacy generated files (conaninfo.txt, conanbuildinfo.txt, etc) are not affected by --output-folder.